# How to maintain the column order when creating a new table using hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

This is my pojo annotated as entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book", catalog = "book_db")
public class Book {
    private Integer bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String bookShortDesc;
    private String bookDesc;
    private String bookAuthor;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "book_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getBookId() {
    return this.bookId;
}

@Column(name = "book_name", nullable = false, length = 256)
public String getBookName() {
    return this.bookName;
}
@Column(name = "book_short_desc", nullable = false, length = 1024)
public String getBookShortDesc() {
    return this.bookShortDesc;
}
```

etc......

the above entity is created using annotation, when i look to the mysql database,the columns are not created in the order, i have written below, instead , first columns is the book_id, then book_desc, then book_athor, then book_short_desc then book_name.

my question is how can i tell hibernate to create the columns the same order as i have written in the java code ??

is there any annotation for that ??

regards

Comment: Your code should never depend on the ordering of columns in the database. In fact, there is technically no guarantee that columns will be returned in a particular order when you SELECT *. If you want the columns in a particular order, specify it in your SQL query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you mean the database tables are generated via `hbm2ddl.auto` being set to `CREATE` or similar, [there is no way to specify the order of the columns](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344) *at least in 2008, according to one member of the Hibernate team*.

My advice would be to create the database via separately maintained database scripts (possibly in conjunction with a script deployment/migration tool such as [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and perhaps also with `hbm2ddl.auto = VALIDATE` to check the resulting schema matches the entities). Maintaining the database via scripts becomes much more necessary once the application goes into production.