# how to create table column in a particular order in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

There is a duplication for my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5964714/5248655) but not yet answered. I'm a beginner to hibernate, while creating table automatically from entity in SQL Server using the property

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

it seems the order of table column is not correct that was not an issue for me until i used composite key. Now the issue is the order of the column is not as same the business entity.
Here is the business entity i created

```
@Entity
public class SalesEstimateDtl implements Serializable {
@Id
private Long LedSalesEstID;
@Id
private Integer LedSalesEstRowNo;
```

and here is the generated query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesEstimateDtl](
             [LedSalesEstRowNo] [int] NOT NULL,
             [LedSalesEstID] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
             (
               [LedSalesEstRowNo] ASC,
               [LedSalesEstID] ASC
             ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can i change the order of LedSalesEstRowNo with LedSalesEstID?

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer, just keen in understanding of the question and the actual answer to the question itself? Why have you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: sorry i was trying use the mobile app for stackOverflow, that went wrong :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the table created with the columns as specified by your annotations shouldn't be dependent on the sequence of it. Neither a `SELECT *` statement would entirely ensure the columns in a specific order as well.

And coming to a response from the Hibernate team, it looks like to be a Known issue and it is not possible to set the order of the columns through Hibernate. Post [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344).

To my understanding, we may not entirely rely on Hibernate's `hbm2ddl` on creating tables. The moment a table is created via Hibernate, we can very well ALTER it to order the columns as needed.

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 3):

Use **@EmbeddedId**

```
 @Entity
    class Student{
        @EmbeddedId
        StudentInfo id;

        String Name;
        String Class;
        Integer RollNo;
    }

    @Embeddable
    class StudentInfo implements serializable {
        Integer StudentID;
        Integer StudentRowNo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Property inside Hibernate Config file

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">showShemaUpdate</property>`

Then Use below code before creating SessionFactory.
    `String file = "SqlSchema.sql";
    SchemaUpdate update = new SchemaUpdate(configuration);
    update.setOutputFile(file);
    update.execute(false, false);`

It will create SqlSchema.sql file in one location which contains all the DDL Queries.Edit them with whatever order you want.